# Funções de cast ou cast direto. Qual é a melhor opção?

Tags: php, desempenho, cast

No PHP, percebo que é possível fazer algumas coisas de inúmeras maneiras.

Uma delas que vem me chamado a atenção são as funções e funcionalidades relacionadas à conversão de tipos. É possível usar tanto a palavra-chave do tipo como usar funções.

Por exemplo:

```
 $var = '1';

 var_dump((int) $var); // int(1)

 var_dump(intval($var)); // int(1);


 var_dump(strval($var)); // string(1)

 var_dump((string) $var); // string(1);
```

Tendo em vista que chamadas de funções costumam consumir mais recursos do que a utilização de um construtor da linguagem ou o operador de `cast`, gostaria de saber:

- Qual é a necessidade de ter essas duas funcionalidades?
- Para um cast de `string` para `int`, por exemplo, qual seria recomendado? Usar o `(int)` ou o `intval`?
- Tendo em vista que chamada de funções costumam consumir  mais recursos do que a chamada de um construtor, existe alguma situação que realmente será necessário usar funções de conversões de tipos, ao invés de cast?

Comment: Se for especificamente sobre conveter uma string em um int talvez essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/139593/91) ajude. Quanto a última pergunta isso depende do rigor exigido pelo código.

Comment: Pelo que leio as recomendações são usar `(int)`, um dos motivos sendo que `intval()` não é tão rápido, o seja cast direto é melhor. `intval` pode, no entanto, receber uma base como segundo argumento. Fontes: https://wiki.phpbb.com/Best_Practices:PHP e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339590/when-should-one-use-intval-and-when-int

Comment: @Miguel já é um início. No caso específico do `intval` tem um segundo parâmetro. Mas devemos lembrar que é apenas um exemplo que usei. No caso a pergunta cabe no sentido de : "Cast vs function"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Tendo em vista que chamadas de funções costumam consumir mais recursos do que a utilização de um construtor da linguagem ou o operador de cast

Isso é falso, pelo menos conceitualmente falando. Uma construção de linguagem pode ser bem complexa. A única coisa de diferente na construção de linguagem é que o compilador tem ciência direta à ela.

Em geral um operador de *cast* ou apenas informa ao compilador que sabe o que está fazendo, e nesse caso é claro que é mais rápido que a função, ou faz uma operação de conversão que é essencialmente o mesmo que chamar a função. Ok, pode ser que a chamada seja ligeiramente pior. Mas pode ser o oposto, tem que ver a real implementação de cada um. Pode ser que o *cast* faça mais coisas ou seja mal feito.

## Diferenças

Claro que há situações onde a função pode ser melhor ou a única opção. Já foi mencionado um segundo parâmetro indicando base de conversão.

Um *cast* não consegue converter qualquer coisa para *string* adequadamente. A função `strval()` pode ter mais sucesso, afinal ela tenta consultar o método [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) para fazer a conversão. O *cast* não faz isso.

Obviamente alguns contextos só aceitam funções. Isso ocorre em funções que esperam que se mande uma *string* com um nome de função para fazer *callback* (coisa horrível de se fazer).

Algumas pessoas acham a função mais legível que o *cast*. Não eu.

Aparentemente a coerção de tipo implícita é feita com *casting*.

## Performance

Por tudo o que leio parece que o *cast* em PHP é sempre mais rápido, pelo menos ligeiramente. Então em tese ele deveria ser usado preferencialmente. Um [teste que achei foi no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35949025/221800). Outro [teste bem completo](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/php-casting-vs-intval/).

Eu fiz um teste parecido em alguns ambientes e obtive diferenças próximas a 50% para melhor no *cast* usando PHP 7 e passando de 200% no PHP 5.x.

O teste foi feito com um algoritmo que faz uma conversão de *string* para `int`, não faria sentido pegar um inteiro para converter para ele mesmo. Mandei [executar milhões de vezes para medir a operação e não a preparação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89622/101).

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OcZAFr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mbiruekw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/CastVsFunction.php). Obviamente esses ambientes são compartilhados e os resultados deles não são confiáveis, faça em seu ambiente com a máquina sem rodar nada que atrapalhe.

Vi o resultado do teste do Daniel Omine. Não vi como foi feito e resultados no 5.6. Vi que o resultado foi de 100 à 200 vezes mais lento que o meu. Porque lá mede mais a interpretação do código do que a operação em si.

É o que eu sempre falo, em muitos casos o PHP terá gasto significativo com a carga e interpretação do código e nem tanto com a sua execução em si. Por isso performance no PHP não é tão importante, afinal o mecanismo já é bem lento. Nesse exemplo a preparação consumiu pelo menos 99% do tempo.

Ressalto que estou especulando um pouco sobre o outro teste já que não mostra como foi feito. Então pode haver engano sobre isso.

Faça seu próprio teste nas circunstâncias que vai usar e fique atento às mudanças em cada versão. O que vale hoje pode não valer amanhã.

Esses testes me indicam que a função é mal feita e o *cast* deve ser preferido, especialmente no PHP 5 onde a diferença é brutal.

## Conclusão

Foi o que consegui procurando na comunidade, que eu não considero a mais confiável. Pode ser isso mesmo, mas pode ter alguma coisa que ninguém percebeu. Não vou me aprofundar nos fontes da linguagem para descobrir, vou confiar. Não parece fazer diferença fundamental.

Comment: A parte que você citou dos callbacks eu imaginava. Usa-se um `intval` e afins com `array_map('intval', ['1', '2'])` por exemplo. Você achar isso horrível também já era esperado :p +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Pelo menos agora tem solução melhor. Aí eu te pergunto, eles criaram uma versão da função, ou modificaram ela para, que aceite uma função anônima como argumento? Ou ainda tem que usar isso? A solução não seria nota 10, mas é a possível e o fato de existir a possibilidade é um belo salto de qualidade.

Comment: `array_map` aceita `Closure` (função anônima) como argumento sim. O problema de passar funções como `string` é que fica bem limitado (passagem de parâmetros). Todo caso, estou preferindo usar `Closure`.

Answer (score 2):

**Testando com casting**

Resumo: 40531158 * 10<sup>−6</sup> (4 milionésimos)

```
//
/*
O tempo tem uma variação
0.0000028610229
0.0000038146973
Normalmente entre 0.0000040531158 e 0.0000050067902
*/
$v = 42;
echo (int)$v;
```

**Testando com a função**

Resumo: 59604645 * 10<sup>−6</sup> (5.9 milionésimos)

```
//
/*
O tempo tem uma variação
0.0000109672546 (quando tem uma pausa de mais de 10 segundos entre uma execução e outra)

Normalmente entre 0.0000059604645 e 0.0000069604645
*/
$v = 42;
echo intval($v);
```

**Observação:**

Após testar várias vezes, ambos passaram a apresentar o mesmo tempo de execução de 5.9 milionésimos por algum tempo.

**Ambiente:**

```
Macbook Pro 2011 (early)
CPU: Intel Core i7 2.2GHz
RAM: 4GB 1333 MHz DDR3

PHP: 7.0.10 (php-osx.liip.ch by Liip)
OS: El Capitan 10.11.6
```

*Testando com PHP 5.5.36, sob o mesmo ambiente, os resultados são idênticos.