# Como funciona a função floatval?

Tags: php, float

Vi na documentação do PHP que existe uma função chamada `floatval()`, para pegar o valor em ponto flutuante de uma variável. Então vi na internet uma pergunta semelhante a essa na internet:

```
$value = '152a.35678';
$value = floatval($value);
echo $value;
```

Qual o valor que será impresso? Porque? Poderiam me explicar mais sobre essa função, e sobre *float*?

Comment: Sua dúvida é em relação a diferença de um cast para `floatval()`?

Comment: Relacionda: [Funções de cast ou cast direto. Qual é a melhor opção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147781/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Breve Introdução ao Float

Retirado da própria *tag* [float](/questions/tagged/float):

> Float é uma abreviação de *Floating Point Number* (Número de ponto flutuante, em inglês). E na maioria das linguagens de programação, esse tipo é usado para variáveis com valores decimais, como `0.1` ou `15.0025`.

#### Float no PHP

Em PHP [existe um problema na confiabilidade](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php) dos pontos flutuantes:

> Números de ponto flutuante tem **precisão limitada** ... Operações matemáticas incomuns **poderão ocasionar erros** maiores, e, claro, a propagação de erros deve ser considerada quando várias operações forem realizadas ... **Então, nunca confie em resultados com números de ponto flutuante** até a última casa, e **nunca compare números de ponto flutuante em igualdades**.

Então é melhor tomar cuidado ao usá-los, seja lá qual seja seu objetivo. Existem perguntas com mais detalhes, que abordam mais profundamente esse assunto que você pode encontrar [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38138/66203) e [aqui também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/66203).

---

A função [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floatval.php) do PHP, como explicada na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floatval.php), obtém o valor em ponto flutuante de uma dada variável. E neste seu caso:

```
$value = '152a.35678';
$value = floatval($value);
echo $value; //imprime 152
```

Irá gerar a saída de `152`. Analisando com `var_dump()`, você pode ver que a variável é do tipo `float`, com valor de `152`.

#### Parâmetros

A função `floatval()` recebe um único parâmetro, que é o valor que você quer obtê-lo o em ponto flutuante.

```
float floatval ( mixed $var )
```

### Notas

Se você coloca letras (aplicável a string em geral), à esquerda será retornado `0`.

```
$var = 'The122.34343';
$float_value_of_var = floatval($var);
echo $float_value_of_var; // imprime 0
```

Mas se você adiciona no fim, ele vai tentar aplicar, a [regra geral de conversão para ponto flutuante](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.casting).

```
$variavel = '122.34343The';
$valor_float = floatval ($variavel);
echo $valor_float; // imprime 122.34343
```

---

Sobre a conversão de tipo, o PHP geralmente já faz isso para você. É por isso que você consegue:

> - Gravar um `int` e acessá-lo como se fosse um ponteiro.
> - **Gravar um `float` e acessar como se fosse um `int`. É certo que o resultado será catastrófico neste caso, mas é possível.**
> - Obter um 0 e ser considerado falso ou outros números (não importa de que tipo) serem interpretados como verdadeiro em operações que exigem um booliano.
> - Gravar dois `short` em sequência e ler como um `int`. Provavelmente nada útil será obtido mas é possível.
> - Gravar "SOpt" e ler isto como se fosse um `int`, sei lá porque.

PHP que é uma linguagem fracamente tipada, permite isso. Você pode ler [mais sobre tipagem forte e 
 fraca aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/66203).