# Qual forma de trocar de variáveis é mais otimizada?

Tags: variáveis, desempenho, memória

Fiz duas formas para trocar os valor `a` e `b`, mas qual é mais otimizada, levando esse exemplo para outras linguagens como desktop ou web.

Sem usar variável auxiliar:

```
$a = 10;
$b = 5;

$a = $b+$a;
$b = $a-$b;
$a -= $b;
```

Usando variável auxiliar:

```
$a = 10;
$b = 5;

$c = $a;
$a = $b;
$b = $c;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, é PHP, certo? Então não importa, a linguagem não foi criada para realizar operações que precisam de extrema otimização.

A comparação chega ser até injusta já que o segundo código está fazendo 3 atribuições simples, o primeiro está fazendo isto e ainda mais 3 operações aritméticas, então fica fácil perceber que a o segundo é mais rápido. Mas a diferença será irrisória. Eu só optaria pelo segundo porque ele também é mais simples.

Comment: Passando esse mesmo código para Java ou C#, etc, teria como medir precisamente a diferença entre elas ?? Pro exemplo, espaço o usado em memória, ou processamento usado.

Comment: Sempre tem como medir.

Comment: Mas tem como complementar sua resposta com a forma de medir ??

Comment: Tem muitas formas, você está ainda adicionando outras linguagens, cada uma tem seu jeito. Quando você faz uma pergunta você tem que decidir o que desejar saber em primeiro lugar. A forma geral é mandar fazer e pegar o tempo de execução. Eu tenho uma resposta sobre isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89622/101

Comment: Talvez, a solicitação de alocação de memória compense o tempo das operações aritméticas, geralmente, pedir recursos ao SO é bem lento, não acha?

Comment: É que não pedirá nada ao sistema operacional. Se é PHP, a memória é gerenciada e não fica pedindo cada alocação necessária e mesmo que pedisse alocar precisa do sistema operacional, atribuir não precisa. No caso, conforme está na resposta. está alocando e atribuindo a mesma quantidade de vezes nos dois casos, a única diferença é que um faz operações aritméticas e o outro não.

Answer (score 1):

A complexidade assintótica de ambas as formas é igual, ou seja, para grandes volumes de operações, a diferença entre ambas é desprezível.

Agora, se você realmente quer medir e comparar o tempo de execução de ambas, no **Java** pode usar o metodo `System.currentTimeMillis()` antes e depois da execução e comparar a diferença.