# Qual o modo mais performático de converter um int na soma de seus dígitos?

Tags: java, algoritmo, desempenho

Tenho um determinado `int` e gostaria de transformá-lo em um outro que seja resultado da soma de seus dígitos da melhor forma possível. Por exemplo:

```
int n = 2601;
```

Deve resultar em `9` já que este é o resultado de `2+6+0+1`. Qual a forma com o melhor desempenho para obter este comportamento?

Baseado [nesta resposta do Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18454515/3388148) vou listar duas formas, mas não pensei em um modo de testar qual tem melhor desempenho e não sei se há alguma outra possibilidade que se sobressaia a essas também:

---

Forma 1:

```
public int somarDigitos(int numero) {
  int resultado = 0;

  while (numero != 0) {
    int digito = numero % 10;
    numero = numero / 10;
    resultado = resultado + digito;
  }

  return resultado;
}
```

---

Forma 2:

```
public int somarDigitos2(int numero) {
  String texto = String.valueOf(numero);
  int resultado = 0;

  for (char digito : texto.toCharArray()) {
    resultado = resultado + Character.getNumericValue(digito);
  }

  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: A primeira alternativa evita a criação de dois objetos (a `String` cria o primeiro objeto, aí o `toCharArray` cria p segundo), então sou tendencioso a achar que a primeira será mais rápida

Comment: Seguindo a linha do comentário acima, acho que evitar `String`s é a melhor opção...

Comment: Quase de certeza que trabalhar só com números é mais rápido que com strings, mas talvez ainda faça uns testes e coloque como resposta

Comment: Cheirinho de problema XY?

Comment: @Sorack Performance depende muito do problema que se quer resolver: é mais "performático" em relação ao tempo de execução? em relação ao uso de memória?... Curto o sistema do SO de perguntas+respostas objetivas, para problemas reais, mas ok, to each his own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A melhor forma de saber qual é mais rápido é fazendo testes executando o algoritmo esperado muitas vezes e comparar.

Claro que o teste precisa de cuidados para não dar resultados tendenciosos. [Respondi algo voltado para C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89622/101), mas quase tudo vale parta Java.

Manipulação de números é uma operação nativa do processador e tem alta performance.

O algoritmo com número fará 3 operações matemática, no máximo 3 transportes de dados (é provável que exista alguma otimização que mantenha algo no registrador e fique bem mais rápido e terá um *branch*, o que pode mais trazer demora, mas acho que a predição de desvio do processador deve funcionar bem neste caso.

Vou descartar a carga necessária para converter a `string` para *array*  de `char` imaginando que a linguagem faça alguma otimização e não precise fazer nada pesado, mas se tiver que realmente fazer um trabalho físico aqui já deve ter um compromisso de performance. A pergunta não quer saber detalhes :)

Tem pelo um *branch* do `for`, talvez mais porque o que eu vi da `getNumericValue()` ela faz verificações sobre a procedência do conteúdo. No mínimo tem uma operação matemática e um transporte dentro da função. Se não conseguir [linearizar a função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110886/101) fica muito pior porque não poderá otimizar para uso de registrador, haverá mais 2 transportes e mais [*overhead*  para gerenciar a chamada da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/101).

Tem uma operação matemática e um transporte visível no código. Mas muita coisa invisível. E parece que esta parte é bem mais pesada do que aparenta.

[Eu fiz um teste](https://ideone.com/108WAO) e a diferença é de duas ordens de magnitude. Mas pode variar em certas circunstâncias. Eu espera uma boa diferença, mas não tão grande assim, por isso que testar é importante.

Testei o algoritmo, porque sequer saber a diferença de desempenho é ele que deve ser analisado.

Testei em ambientes diferentes e os resultados foram consistentes.

Porém em uso real tem uma série e outras coisas para resolver. E me parece que o Java não é bom de otimizar isto. Se você chamar uma função com o algoritmo a chamada da função pesará muito e coloca os dois algoritmo mais perto da paridade.

Se não tiver algo que eu não sei fazer no Java faz muita diferença chamar uma função ou executar de forma direta. Aí fica para os Javeiros com larga experiência nisso falar. Admito que posso ter errado na avaliação, mas nada fácil de perceber.

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String []args) {
        int numero = 123456;
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            int resultado = 0;
            while (numero != 0) {
                numero /= 10;
                resultado += numero % 10;
            }
        }
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - time) + "ns");
        time = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            String texto = String.valueOf(numero);
            int resultado = 0;
            for (char digito : texto.toCharArray()) {
                resultado = resultado + Character.getNumericValue(digito);
            }
        }
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - time) + "ns");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GlbLsh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pdnjgomx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Performance.java).

Comment: Sobre a sua metodologia, refaço a observação que fiz ao @Isac. Também questiono que você fez com um só tamanho de inteiro. Tamanhos distintos talvez pudesse oferecer uma análise para detectar a mudança de _branch_.

Comment: Eu testei o que ele criou, se eu testar com alguma outra coisa aí não é o que ele está propondo.

Comment: Minha crítica não é em relação ao que foi testado :-) Mas sim que na sua medição acaba entrando o tempo de manutenção do laço. 1.000.000 (ou são mais do que 6 zeros?) de incrementos e comparações e desvios que não fazem parte do que realmente está sendo estudado acabam entrando na medição. Detalhes de metodologia, mas ainda assim uma pulga atrás da minha orelha fica me cutucando. Assim como a invocação de lambdas nas minhas medições também me incomoda...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu concordo, como você eliminaria isto?

Comment: Pensei em duas alternativas: (a) fazer a medição do que se está medindo, granularmente, dentro do `for` e não fora dele; essa medição eu creio que não seja confiável porque talvez o retorno granular não seja confiável. (b) medir um controle fazendo o laço e `noop`, então descontar o tempo do controle dos tempos medidos; também não sei se é confiável, se o `jitter` tentará fazer alguma otimização com meu `noop`...

Comment: Nunca fiz no Java, mas em todos os testes que fiz em outras plataformas não dá certo.